# How often can I boost with a perfect power distributor?

Tags: elite-dangerous

I'm researching a build for my Krait Phantom ratship right now, and the last piece of the puzzle is the power distributor. I know I need at least [a certain size power distributor](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/326974/how-does-power-distributor-size-affect-boost-capability) to be able to boost at all, but that's not what I'm after. I want the smallest power distributor possible while still being able to boost forever. I'm using [coriolis.io](https://coriolis.io/) to put my build together, which gives me a "boost time" number, which is how fast your power distributor will recharge enough ENG power for a boost.

So my question is, how often can you boost supposing your ENG power never depletes, or recharges faster than your boost key accepts input? What number should I be looking for in coriolis to determine that my ship is able to boost forever?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approximately once every 5 seconds**. In the particular case of my build, this meant that a 4A Power Distributor with Engine Focused was adequate, giving me a boost time of 0:04, however, you may have to experiment a bit for your own build. Access to Jameson Memorial helps out quite a bit with this experimentation process.

Another thing to keep in mind is that reducing weight by dropping a size class has diminishing returns. Going from a 7A to a 6A saves 40T of weight and adds around 4LY of range to my build, but going from a 4A to a 3A only saves 5T of weight and would only add around 0.5LY. Is it possible that the 3A with engine focused and an experimental effect is good enough? Maybe. Is it worth engineering that for a measly 0.5LY, when my range is already 62LY? No.